# system() call with batch executable ofstream files make program reset on windows

Tags: c++, batch-file

When I "Build and Run" the program from Code::Blocks it works perfectly! But when I run it manually from "/bin" folder, when it tries to call a "temp.bat" with system(), it resets. Why is that?
It doesn't have specific files to depend, it creates them itself.
Here is some code:

```
         ofstream filetmp1 ("temp1.bat", ios::out | ios::binary);
               filetmp1 << "@echo off" << '\n';
               filetmp1 << "echo user xyz> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp1 << "echo xyz>> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp1 << "echo get conntest.test>> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp1 << "echo bye>> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp1 << "ftp -n -s:script.dat xyz.com" << '\n';
               filetmp1 << "del script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp1.close();
               system ("temp1.bat");            //IF I REMOVE THIS LINE, THE PROGRAM WORKS HOW IT SHOULD, until the second system("temp1.bat")
               system ("del temp1.bat");
               system ("cls");

    cout << "All data loaded!"; Sleep(1500);
    system("cls");

    ofstream filetmp ("temp1.bat", ios::out | ios::binary);
               filetmp << "@echo off" << '\n';
               filetmp << "echo user xyz> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp << "echo xyz>> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp << "echo cd app>> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp << "echo lcd data>> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp << "echo prompt n>> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp << "echo mput *.txt>> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp << "echo bye>> script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp << "ftp -n -s:script.dat xyz.com" << '\n';
               filetmp << "del script.dat" << '\n';
               filetmp.close();
               system ("temp1.bat");                //WITH BOTH LINES REMOVED, IT WORKS. But I do not want to remove them, because I don't know alternative ways for them
               system ("del temp1.bat");
               system ("cls");
```

I think I said all the details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question could really use a [mcve].

Comment: @IsaacLyman thanks, I revised it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by reset? Also, if you take out the delete call, is a temp1.bat even created? If so, can you run temp1.bat manually from cmd.exe?

Comment: @define,  by reset I mean the program goes to the beginning, it starts again. And yes, the file is created and I executed temp1.bat from cmd successfully.

Comment: "You must explicitly flush—by using fflush or _flushall—or close any stream before you call system." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx. I'd be surprised if this is the problem, but since you appear to have `<iostream>` included, try flushing cout, cin, and cerr before calling system? (Probably using _flushall() is easiest)

Comment: @definecindyconst thank you! I had to close any stream indeed.

Comment: Moving my comment to an answer so the question can be marked answered / answer is easier to find if anyone else is looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "You must explicitly flush—by using fflush or _flushall—or close any stream before you call system." - [MS Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx)

Try flushing all the streams that need to be left open during the `system` call. `_flushall()` should be easiest.